# Apache Nifi Processor for Signature Verification

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I have developed a JAVA application for signature verification as follows:

```
    package read_key_pck;

    import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.Security;
    import java.security.Signature;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.util.Base64;

    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

    public class Main {

    public final static String RESOURCES_DIR = "C:\\Users\\KX5710\\eclipse-workspace\\read_key\\src\\read_key_pck\\";

    public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

        byte[] signatureBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(signature); 

        return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        PublicKey pub = null;
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        try {

            pub = generatePublicKey(factory, RESOURCES_DIR
                    + "rsa_2048_pub.pem");

        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String encodedPublicKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pub.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("publickey: " + encodedPublicKey);

        boolean isCorrect = verify("         4   5.00   1.80", "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", pub);
        System.out.println("Signature verification: " + isCorrect);
    }

    private static PublicKey generatePublicKey(KeyFactory factory,
            String filename) throws InvalidKeySpecException,
            FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        PemFile pemFile = new PemFile(filename);
        byte[] content = pemFile.getPemObject().getContent();
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(content);
        return factory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    }
}

    package read_key_pck;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
    import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;

    public class PemFile {

        private PemObject pemObject;

        public PemFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(filename)));
            try {
                this.pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
            } finally {
                pemReader.close();
            }
        }

        public PemObject getPemObject() {
            return pemObject;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to develop an Apache Nifi Processor for this JAVA application; I have a sample code here :

https://github.com/pcgrenier/nifi-examples

However I do not know that I have to modify which parts of this sample code, since it is the first time i develop an Apache Nifi Processor.

Also When I want to run .bat file in cmd i.e. run-nifi.bat I get this error :

> "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. Instead
>   the PATH will be used to find the java executable."

Answer (score 2):

Here is detailed guide for beginners https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4318/build-custom-nifi-processor.html .
The above article is based on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ldmNFlelhw

Briefly explanation:

1. You should create the new project from one of the NiFi maven archetype.
2. Modify generated processor to your needs.
3. Build the nar file and put it to NiFi.
4. Use it in NiFi.

Comment: I installed maven as described https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/ but when i run "mvn –version" i receive this error : "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\KX5710). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory"

Comment: You have invalid `–` symbol. It's looks like em dash, but it's should be minus. You can copy this: "mvn -version"

Comment: @ Vitaliy Samofal  Thanks you. i have read https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/ and i did the steps but i did not understand section 2.7 what is this IP address? I get time out error when i want to connect to it to copy nar file. Also how to restart nifi ? Thanks

Comment: I don't sure what 2.7 section you are taking about. About restarting, it's depends on, how do you install it. I suppose, that you just download it, and run .bat file. If yes, than you can refer this https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/getting-started.html#for-windows-users . Just click ctrl+c, and run .bar again.

Comment: I am talking about this section: 2.7Copy the nar file to Nifi
"Copy the nar file to the bin directory of where nifi is installed
Here is a sample command to copy the file --
scp nifi-demo-nar-1.0.nar root@172.16.149.157:/opt/nifi-1.0.0.0-7/bin/

Once the nar file is copied youi need to restart nifi
Once restarted you should be able to add the custom processor that you built which will show up with the name "MyProcessor"" https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4318/build-custom-nifi-processor.html

Comment: I see, you don't need this, it's for the case when NiFi installed somewhere. You need to copy your `nar` file, to your NiFi ${NIFI_PATH}/bin directory, and then restart NiFi.

Comment: @ Vitaliy Samofal  Thanks, would you plz say nifi download link ? i found a bin file it is the same ?

Comment: @ Vitaliy Samofal  I copied ti nifi bin directory, but since nifi is a bin file how can i restart it ? Thanks

Comment: Is NiFi currently started?

Comment: @ Vitaliy Samofal  When i want to run .bat file in cmd i.e. run-nifi.bat i get this error : java_home environment variable is not defined correctly

Answer (score 2):

Great that you're writing your own custom processor on NiFi. Couple of things that you have to keep in mind:

- The core functionality that your processor intends to do goes inside the overridden `onTrigger` method.
- Handling relationships of your processor (Failure/Success)

Couple of guides that would help in your quest:

- http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/
- https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/02/04/custom-processors-for-apache-nifi

The first one provides you some overview on common terminologies & functionalities in the form of annotation and classes that are widely used in NiFi processors and also provide relevant links to the same on [Apache NiFi developer guide](https://nifi.apache.org/developer-guide.html). That tutorial itself should be able to get you started with the actual implementation since it has examples in the form of code and POM.

Comment: When I want to run .bat file in cmd i.e. run-nifi.bat I get this error : "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. Instead the PATH will be used to find the java executable." Thank you for your help also I can not find my processor at http://localhost:8080/nifi/

Comment: In case you have renamed your processor, have you updated the same in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor` ?

Comment: Here is content of processor file: "scc.processors.demo.MyProcessor" I did not change it. but why do i receive "JAVA_HOME environment variable" error ?

Comment: Do you have `JAVA_HOME` set in your system's environment variable? Otherwise, you can point to the Java installation directory  in the `nifi-env.bat`

Comment: yes i did. for the first time i run .bat file i did not receive this error, but for the second time ....